# Evaluating a contour integral along two paths

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm working on the following problem:

Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \overline{z}^{2}dz$ along $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the straight-line joining $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

I defined $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\gamma (t) = t+it$. Then using the definition of the contour integral,

$\int_{0}^{1} -2it^{2}(1+i)dt = \frac{2}{3}-\frac{2i}{3}$.

Is this correct? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I would change this to "I'm working on the following problem:

Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \overline{z}^{2}dz$ along the straight-line joining $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$."

Comment: You didn't give the second path, but the integral over the straight-line path is computed correctly.

Comment: And this choice of gamma is correct? I see that the endpoints are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, but I was not sure if that was all I needed to have in my gamma function.

Comment: You need a parametrization which is bijective between $[t_1, t_2]$ and $[0, 1 + i]$ (the segment between $0$ and $1 + i$) and is smooth. It's not unique, but any such parametrization will give the same result. Your $\gamma(t)$ matches the requirements.